# Creating type of ranking map on ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, legend

I wanted to create a ranking continuous legend ...but everytime symbology come in class interval with different box of colour ramp . [image]

Comment: What's yhe layer type? Is it Raster or Vector?

Comment: Is it a classified or continuous renderer (in the symbology tab)? What format is the product being viewed? Some formats resample the colours to 8bit so you will see stepping in continuous colour ramps, for example GIF, PNG. Others have control over the bit depth and may be set to 8bit like PDF, EPS.

Answer (score 1):

You can create legend with a new layer.

1. Draw a graphic in arcmap:

[image]

2. Change graphic to a feautre: Right click to a dataframe => click convert graphics to Features.

[image]

3. Select source data if you have a source data. click ok.
4. In the new feature class, Righ click and select properties. Go to Symbology tab.
5. Select symbol => in Symbol Selector window, click edit symbol.

[image]

6. Select Gradient Symbol in 'Type" section.

[image]

7. Select your color ramp. Set "Intervals" to 100, "Percentage" to 90  and "Angle" to 90, -90 or 0 .Leave "style: to Linear.

[image]

8. Add Text to the feture in Layout View.

[image]
[image]